# C# yield return

Tags: c#, file, foreach

I have this method GetWordsArray below, and when I call the method in the main program it only prints out whole sentences which start with the specific letter.

```
    public static void GetWordsArray(string path, string toFind)
    {
        string[] words = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        if (File.Exists(path)) 
        {              
            foreach (string line in words)
            {
                if(line.StartsWith(toFind))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }                  
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Directory not found");
        }
    }
```

This is how I call the method in the main program:

```
    Reader r = new Reader();            
    string path = @"randomtext.txt";
    Reader.GetWordsArray(path, "b");
```

How can I print out all the words from the text file which start with the letter b for example?

Comment: 1. Show where you are outputting to console, 2. why are you looping and yield returning when you can just return `lines`?

Comment: Why you are re-implementing [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx)? Also please make sure to provide [MCVE] that shows how you output results.

Comment: I need to yield return it because it is a school assignment and must use it -.- dunno how.

Comment: Asking something that is not related to your problem is not productive. Please make sure to [edit] the post with clear problem and what exactly you don't understand. Code in the post and your comments don't align at all (as code looks ok and shows that OP of the code knows how `yield` is used)

Comment: I asked a new question, thanks for the tips, I hope this question is more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (string item in GetWords(@"C:\Temp\file.txt"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ", item);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<String> GetWords(string path) 
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(path))
            {
                yield return line;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Directory not correct");
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return File.ReadAllLines(path).AsEnumerable();`???? Array already is `IEnumerable` - reading whole file and then pretending it is lazy enumerable is very strange suggestion.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, Yes sorry good point, dont have VS handy so threw something together.

Comment: Can you show me how to yield return it? The code you provided is good, but it is a school assignment and must follow the requirements.

Comment: @meesie1  Detail why you need yield.

Comment: I first did it in a try catch, it worked but after reading the assignment I needed to add yield return, I added it and the code also suggested it but you cant use a yield return in a try catch, after searching for hours, I ended up doing this approach.

Comment: Sorry, I figured out what you are wanting to do. I have updated the code. Here is a good description on yield keyword https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield

Comment: Thank you for your time to help me, now I can go on. I just think really complex when it comes to code.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your method was on a class called Hello. Then you could call it like this.

```
 Hello hello = new Hello();
 string path = @"D:\Data\words.txt";
 var lines = hello.GetWords(path);
 foreach (var line in lines)
 {
      Console.WriteLine(line);
 }
```

You do have some redundancy in your method in that you can simply return the lines variable and it would work the same way. Yield is used when writing iterators.